# How can i get element id in js function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

JS doesn't see input ID(undefined). I have no idea why it doesn't work. I found many solutions in google, but it still doesn't work.

index.html :

```
<div ng-class="{'form-group has-success':checkValue(answer) == true,'form-group has-warning': checkValue(answer) == false}">
    <input id="422" 
        maxlength="3" 
        type="Integer" 
        class="form-control" 
        style="width: 100px" 
        ng-model="answer" 
        ng-blue="checkValue(answer, id)">
</div>
```

```js
$scope.checkValue = function(value, id) {
    $scope.val = id;
    console.log($scope.val);
    if ($scope.val == value)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The console just shows:

```
undefined
```

Comment: console.log(this.id);

Comment: You are calling the function `checkValue()` with only the first argument. Therefore the second argument `id` is undefined In your last function call you only use `id`, instead use  this.id

Comment: Side note: Avoid setting numbers as elements IDs.

Comment: console.log(this.id); - doesn't work

Comment: if u meaning this line {'form-group has-success':checkValue(answer) == true,'form-group has-warning': checkValue(answer) == false}, it still desn't work

Comment: where is the script, try putting it at the bottom of the page before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 1):

with jquery:

```
(function($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var inputId = $('input').attr('id');
        console.log(inputId)
    });
})( jQuery );
```

with pure javascript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var inputId = inputs[i].id;
console.log(inputId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID by using the following code:

```
$('ELEMENT').attr('id');
```

You can also use this code for getting other attributes as class name etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID by using the following code:

$('.form-control').attr('id');

Answer (score 0):

You can get ID by following code:

```
var element_id = $("input[ng-model='answer']").attr("id"); //Here I am using other unique property of the element to get its attribute
```

You can also make use other property also or else you can make use of other Jquery selector like this

```
var element_id = $(".form-control").attr("id"); //This may give unexpected result if class name is repeated
```

or

```
var element_id = $("input.form-control").attr("id"); //This is more assuring way since, we are providing class name along with element name
```